# Hit-Testing a Transparent Element in a Transparent Window

Tags: wpf

In WPF, I have a `Border` whose `Background` is set to `Transparent`. It is inside of a `Window`, whose `AllowsTransparency` is set to `True` and whose `Background` is null.

However, the `Border` is invisible to mouse clicks as well despite the fact that its background is transparent and not null. It is only hit if there is a non-transparent element behind it - however, I want the completely transparent parts of the border to also register clicks.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a nearly transparent brush to your control background.

Try this code below:

```
<Border Background="#01FFFFFF" />
```

or this one:

```
<Border Background="#01000000" />
```

Comment: That does indeed work, however, I would like to avoid this if possible. The user is not likely to notice the difference, but I am striving for perfection.

Comment: @laptou I know, and I've tried something more such as transparent bitmap image. But all don't work. I'm reading more to find out better solution.